# Ternary inline ASP.NET in Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, ternary-operator

Imagine that I have a link button called "readMore" in the `ItemTemplate` of a repeater, and I want to set `display: none;` for it, when the content of each post is less than say, 2000 characters.

```
<asp:repeater id="postsRepeater" runat="server" 
  onitemdatabound="postsRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <a class="button" href="#" runat='server' id='more'>Read More</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

In PHP, you can simply write something like:

```
<?php echo (contentLength < 2000 ? 'display: none;' : ''); ?>
```

However, I tested this code and it trowed and error:

```
<%= Eval("Content").Length < 2000 ? "display: none;" : string.Empty %>
```

Is it possible to write ternary inline ASP.NET in a Repeater control? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an issue of ternary operator; it is an issue of Databound controls because you have to use `#` instead of `=`.

Use this

```
<%# Eval("Content").ToString().Length < 2000 ? "display: none;" : string.Empty %>
```

Instead of

```
<%= Eval("Content").ToString().Length < 2000 ? "display: none;" : string.Empty %>
```

Comment: Also Eval returns object so you need to cast or convert the result to string in order to get the length.