# ASP.NET ternary operator on the Session variable

Tags: asp.net, ternary-operator, asp.net-session

I'm trying to use the ternary operator to add a css class to a `TextBox` if the `Session` variable contains a particular value:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMyTextBox" Width="70px"
  class='role-based jsSpinner <%= Session["MyVariable"] == "MyValue" ? "ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" : ""  %>' />
```

I can confirm that `MyVariable` has the `MyValue` value, however, when I run the application, the class doesn't get applied. I found several other similar questions but they all use the ternary operator for a binding expression (using `<%# %>`) and not for evaluating the Session variable. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline expressions are not parsed in attributes for controls with runat="server". However, you can use data bind expressions.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649458/991267) for info about major difference between **<%= %>** and **<%# %>** syntax.

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();
    }

    string Foo()
    {
        return (string)Session["MyVariable"] == "MyValue" ? "ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" : "";
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass='<%# Foo() %>' />
```

Also you try to compare object reference and string reference. Need to cast the object to string to make the equals operator work.

```
bool test1 = (string)Session["MyVariable"] == "MyValue";

bool test2 = String.Compare((string)Session["MyVariable"], "MyValue") == 0;
```

---

```
object myString = 1.ToString();

// false
// Warning: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'
bool bad = myString == "1";

// true
bool good1 = (string)myString == "1";

// true
bool good2 = String.Compare((string)myString, "1") == 0;
```

Comment: Running a `.ToString()` on `Session["UserRole"]` doesn't fix it either. Also, this on the `aspx` side and not in the code behind.

Comment: Extract the line into a function and debug it.

Comment: This is an `aspx` syntax. Can't exactly debug it. I don't have any issues debugging C# code mate. This is more like a syntax error.

Comment: Inline expressions do not work for controls with runat="server".

Comment: [Pretty sure they do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009834/ternary-inline-asp-net-in-repeater-control). Also, if that was the case, how would you explain inline data-binding expressions? It's not any different from this.

Comment: An answer by your link uses data-binding syntax. I added an example with data binding. It's easy to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it still doesn't address my issue.

Comment: You're right, turns out `<%=` expressions are not allowed for server controls.

Comment: You may wanna remove the string comparison part though. That has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, no cast is needed. I bet the string is not in the session. Use your debugger. This worked for me in VS 2008 C#

```
<%Session["foo"] = "bar"; %>
<div class='<% = Session["foo"] == "bar" ? "yes":"no" %>'>
```

Comment: Robert, you're wrong. Cast is required. Try the following code:             Session["foo"] = 123.ToString();
            Response.Write(Session["foo"] == "123" ? "1-success" : "1-fail");
            Response.Write((string)Session["foo"] == "123" ? "2-success" : "2-fail");

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I already confirmed that the value exists.

Comment: Generally casting is poor style and should be used in rare situations with a good comment about why you are doing it.